# Printing a div on 80 mm wide paper

Tags: javascript, php, printing

I've invested in an epson TM-T20II printer, with 80 mm wide paper.

I have a script that makes me print a specific hidden div with some text, but the problem is, the text is printede with approx 20 mm. margins to both sides and twice as much blank paper at the bottom as there are text.

How can i set this up?

My code look like:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://jqueryjs.googlecode.com/files/jquery-1.3.1.min.js" > </script> 
<script type="text/javascript">

    function PrintElem(elem)
    {
        Popup($(elem).html());
    }

    function Popup(data) 
    {
        var mywindow = window.open('', 'my div', 'height=50mm,width=80mm');
        mywindow.document.write('<html><head><title>Handskemager Dans</title>');
        /*optional stylesheet*/ //mywindow.document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" type="text/css" />');
        mywindow.document.write('</head><body >');
        mywindow.document.write(data);
        mywindow.document.write('</body></html>');

        mywindow.document.close(); // necessary for IE >= 10
        mywindow.focus(); // necessary for IE >= 10

        mywindow.print();
        mywindow.close();
        popupWindow.hide ();

        return true;
    }

</script>
```

And the div is just:

```
  <div id="mydiv" style="width:80mm;display:none;">
</div>
```

Hope you can help, i cant find anything in the printer settings.

Comment: Have you tried `* {padding: 0; margin: 0}` to turn off browser default margin and padding?

Comment: I just tried it, but it's still the same, any other sugestions?

Comment: Or is there another way to print a specific text and then change the size of the paper thats beeing printed

Comment: If you print only simple `Hello` without any HTML, does it starts from top left corner without any margins?

Answer (score 1):

i found the answer.

I just used Chrome instead of Firefox and set the paper size to "Paper Roll 80 mm" and then set the margins to "Minimum" then everything came out perfect.